# No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 18.974000 seconds. Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
i already searched this question on all over answers.ros.org, but i didnt found answer on the issue i have. I built a custom 4 wheel bot and i added a navigation stack(map, move_base, amcl and other param yaml files) on it. if  i run the launch file, i get this error,

**[ WARN] [1656224367.752167333, 18.974000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 18.974000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.**

so, the issue i have is even if i see the map in rviz, there are no particle filters i can see detected by laser.Which describes the error i mentioned above. i clearly understand that my bot doesnt localize at first, leads to cant set a navigate and set a goal to my bot on the map.

I have been trying to solve this issue since last 3 days. Would be glad to have some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402927/no-laser-scan-received-(and-thus-no-pose-updates-have-been-published)-for-18.974000-seconds.--verify-that-data-is-being-published-on-the-/scan-topic./) by [the_one](https://answers.ros.org/users/109236/the_one/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2022-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2022-06-28**:
You'd better provide the result when executing `roswtf`, and the tf tree in rqt. It is easier for others to debug

**Comment by [the_one](https://answers.ros.org/users/109236/the_one/) on 2022-06-29**:
thank u for ur reply
Sure, i attached a link of drive here, which has all the image files(error) in it...for your reference.

[link text](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1itqJhTRxgLH6o-jex__odOscBCi2puP3?usp=sharing)

i named those files with respect to the errors...

thanks in advance.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2022-07-02**:
any output from the /scan topic using rostopic echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, after many consideration and references, i finally got cleared that issue. Fault is on me. I did the mistake on topic name. Its working now. After that i wanted to scan the map(turtlebot3 house) with my bot, but it ended up like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmrK8JD5FFObT-juoNvC5oTuddomcyrI/view?usp=sharing). Also if i run the launch file, the bot behaves like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W4G43MYQE6IfXx_a61cEl5_bXDUgP_CI/view?usp=sharing). Idk why the bot behaves like. Thanks in advance.

---

Originally posted by [the_one](https://answers.ros.org/users/109236/the_one/) with karma: 41 on 2022-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0